# Is it possible to draw graphics in Visual C++ 2010 Express?

Tags: c++

Is it possible to write/draw graphics (3D & 2D) using Visual C++ 2010 Express?  (I found a series of tutorials on youtube about game programming, but 'ttraps'-the guy who made them- never got to graphics. His last post was in 2010.) 
If so, what project type should I build and what library headers do I need?
If this is impossible, please direct me to some other resources that I could use.
(I am using Windows 7.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a whole range of libraries for drawing graphics using C/C++.

If you are on Windows and not afraid to use platform dependent code then you can use the [Windows GDI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphics_Device_Interface) API. GDI is usually used to build interactive GUI Widgets, such as custom drawn buttons and edit boxes.

If you are looking for 3D rendering you can use Microsoft's own [DirectX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DirectX) API. There is also an [OpenGL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenGL) Windows implementation.

Comment: If you include <windows.h> you will get all the necessary headers for using the GDI API. To start you could look at something like BeginPaint/EndPaint functions, which will give you a handle (HDC) to the Window surface to begin drawing. The drawing functions, for example, LineTo, will accept the HDC handle.

Comment: infact                                                          What kind of project can I include <windows.h> in?               Also I have downloaded DirectX, but all I got was a bunch of non-indexed folders with .dll files, and a couple of 'DirectX SDK' notepad files. Did the download not work properly or did I download the wrong thing?

Comment: Well you need the Windows ("Plastform") SDK installed, this comes with Visual Studio. DirectX is just a library, but you should get a CHM documentation file with it that describes the API. I would have expected the installer to place shortcuts to these on the start menu.

Comment: infact Does the Windows Plastform( or did you mean platform?) SDK come with Visual C++ 2010 Express as well? Or do I have to buy Visual Studio? And do I have to move the DirectX libraries to a certain place or leave them as they are?"

Comment: You can leave the DX libraries where they are, but you'll need to configure the linker so that it knows where to find them. Platform (sorry typo) SDK comes with Visual Studio 2010 Express, if not you can always download the latest version from the Microsoft website.

Comment: infact Is the platform SDK part of Visual Studio, or is it a separate application? And how do you configure the linker? I found something titled 'Aditional Directories' in Project properties under Linker, do I have to give the names of the DirectX folders or .dll files in the folders?

Comment: It comes with Visual Studio, it should be in Visual Studio Express too. The DirectX installer should set up Visual Studio for you. You have to give the linker (in Additional Libraries) the same of the DirectX .lib files.

Comment: Is .lib the same as .dll? Because I only seem to have .dll files. Also there are about 75 folders with either one or two .dll files in each of them, is there like a 'home' file which can access all the other files? Or do I have to name all of them? And thanks for all the help, you've spent a fair bit of time on this question.

Comment: You should open up some new questions. To use a .dll you need to link with its import library (.lib), so they go hand in hand. You probably only need one or two .lib (and .dll) to use most of the features of DirectX. On MSDN the library and headers are listed on each API page :)